# Compare the values in different rows of a dataframe and create new dataframe with rows satisfying the conditions

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a requirement to apply some logic on different rows of a dataframe and create a new dataframe with rows only satisfying the logic.

The input dataframe is as shown below.

```
+------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| NUM_ID     | E           |SG1_V|SG2_V|SG3_V|SG4_V|
+------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|XXXXX01     |1570167499000|     |     | 89.0|     |
|XXXXX01     |1570167502000|     |88.0 |     |     |
|XXXXX01     |1570167503000|     |99.0 |     |     |
|XXXXX01     |1570179810000|81.0 |81.0 |81.0 |81.0 |
|XXXXX01     |1570179811000|92.0 |     |95.0 |     |
|XXXXX01     |1570179833000|     |     |88.0 |     |
|XXXXX02     |1570179840000|     |81.0 |     |81.0 |
|XXXXX02     |1570179841000|81.0 |     |81.0 |81.0 |
|XXXXX02     |1570179841000|     |     |     |     |
|XXXXX02     |1570179842000|81.0 |     |     |     |
|XXXXX02     |1570179843000|87.0 |98.0 |97.0 |88.0 |
|XXXXX02     |1570179849000|     |     |     |     |
|XXXXX03     |1570179850000|     |     |     |     |
|XXXXX03     |1570179852000|88.0 |     |     |     |
|XXXXX03     |1570179857000|     |     |     |88.0 |
|XXXXX03     |1570179858000|     |     |     |88.0 |
```

I have to check the values for each **SG_V** columns such a way that the difference between the each **SG_V** for a **NUM_ID** is greater than 10. The difference value of 10 for a single **SG_V** or multiple **SG_V** columns in a row will be considered as a single row.

It will be clear once you have a look at expected output.
expected output is as below.

```
+------------+-------------+------------+-----+------------+-----+------------+-----+------------+-----+
| NUM_ID     | E           |PREVIOUS_SG1|SG1_V|PREVIOUS_SG2|SG2_V|PREVIOUS_SG3|SG3_V|PREVIOUS_SG4|SG4_V|
+------------+-------------+------------+-----+------------+-----+------------+-----+------------+-----+
|XXXXX01     |1570167503000|            |     | 88.0       |99.0 |            |     |            |     |
|XXXXX01     |1570179811000|81.0        |92.0 |            |     |81.0        |95.0 |            |     |

|XXXXX02     |1570179843000|            |     |81.0        |98.0 |81.0        |97.0 |            |     |
```

Thanks in Advance! Any leads appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like that:

I calculated differences, then checked if it's > 10, put into array of booleans and finally checked if contains false values using `array_contains`

```
  import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val df = Seq(
    (10, 21, 32, 43),
    (10, 20, 30, 40),
    (1, 2, 3, 4),
    (1, 100, 200, 300)
  ).toDF().withColumn("id",monotonically_increasing_id())

  df.show()

  val cols = df.columns.dropRight(1)
  var pairs: Array[(String, String)] = new Array[(String, String)](cols.length - 1)
  for (i <- 0 to cols.length - 2) {
    pairs(i) = (cols.apply(i), cols.apply(i + 1))
  }

  println("pairs:")
  pairs.foreach(print(_))

  val calcDiff = array_contains(
    array(
      pairs.map(s=>(df(s._2)-df(s._1))>10):_*
    ), false
  )

  df.filter(calcDiff).show()
```

output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3| _4| id|
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 10| 21| 32| 43|  0|
| 10| 20| 30| 40|  1|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  2|
|  1|100|200|300|  3|
+---+---+---+---+---+

pairs:
(_1,_2)(_2,_3)(_3,_4)

+---+---+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3| _4| id|
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 10| 21| 32| 43|  0|
|  1|100|200|300|  3|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```